# How crond working in an alpine docker container?

Tags: docker, cron, containers

I'm using this configuration in the project folder :

`./infra/test/crontab` :

```
* * * * * echo 'Test $(date)' >> /var/www/html/log.log
```

`./infra/test/Dockerfile` :

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --update busybox-suid
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data infra/test/crontab /etc/crontabs/www-data
RUN chmod 0755 /etc/crontabs/www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/html

USER www-data

CMD ["exec", "crond", "-l", "0", "-d", "0", "-f"]
```

In my project folder i'm using these commands :

1. `docker build -t test_cron -f ./infra/test/Dockerfile .` to build container
2. `docker run -it test_cron sh` to go inside the container

In my container, I'm waiting a moment, and I check the crontab list :

```
/var/www/html $ crontab -l
* * * * * echo 'Test $(date)' >> /var/www/html/log.log
```

But they are no logs in the folder :

```
/var/www/html $ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx    2 www-data www-data      4096 Jun 11 18:52 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jun 11 18:52 ..
```

I don't understand why... Any ideas ?

Comment: When you `docker run your-image sh`, the `sh` command is the only thing the container runs; it runs _instead of_ the `CMD` in the image.

Comment: Ok, so if y want to see if it's working, I need to add a shared volume dans start the container, then I will see if it's good ?

Comment: I just tests it, but I haven't got log